# TFS Build randomly wont run

Tags: build, tfs, msbuild

We have a TFS 2010 build server. After running a Queue Build upon a build definition of a VS sln or msbuild file, randomly (around 30%) the build process won't run. The build log window showed only 3 tabs: Activity Log, Next Error, and Next Warning. After a few minutes, say 10 minutes, I had to press the Stop Build. The build server is not busy at all.

Have you seen/heard similar things? Could you help?

Cheers

Comment: What are the errors you are receiving in the Build Output?

Comment: No build output. The whole thing waited at the very beginning. Normally at the beginning when things are running well, you would expect to see: Overall Build Process

00:00
Update Build Number

00:00
Create the Drop Location

00:00
 Run On Agent (reserved build agent XXX Build Agent)

00:00
Delete Test Results Directory

00:00
Delete Binaries Directory

00:00
Delete Workspace

00:00
Delete Sources Directory

00:00
Create Workspace

00:01
Get Workspace

Comment: Is there not a message such as: "The process cannot access the file 'data.coverage' because it is being used by another process."? I had a zombie process issue a few months back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you give it a try to let him run until the timeout is reached. From your comments it looks like he is doing the Get Workspace when you stop the build. Please check the workspace that is defined for your build definition. I had one a project team that created there own build and wondered why it takes so long to build, unfortunately the included the whole TeamProject (about 6GB), which were getted every time the build was queued.

While it randomly works, does it depend on the build agent that is used or do you just have one build agent?

Comment: I think it could be the some dependencies of the tfs servers had some strange problems randomly because of the doggy network config. However, I did not have the admin access to the network. Nevertheless, though not resolved, I think MikeR's answer is close to at least one of the causes.